# Is there any reason to keep sticking to a 3-letter file extension for modern platforms?

Tags: file, cross-platform, naming-conventions

I am developing a new application, and in the process of working on the file-save system want to use a file extension that is properly indicative as belonging to the application. The group that will be using this application are very accustomed to referring to themselves by a four-letter acronym that cannot be easily shortened to a 3-letter acronym that is still representative of their name...

I would like to use their acronym as a 4-letter file extension, but this flies in the face of the ages old 3-letter 'standard'. But then, so do .html, .aspx, etc.

Is there any reason for an application meant to be cross-platform (Windows XP+, Android, iOS, Linux) to continue to stick to the 3-letter convention, or is it OK to use a 4-letter?

Comment: A down vote a mere 2 minutes after posting the question. Any reason?

Comment: I see no problem with using a longer extension; it is common enough now.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulLefebvre -- I had assumed as much, given that some popular formats use it. I just wanted confirmation there isn't some hidden, less obvious reason not to do so.